# How to create Multi-pages in PDF file created with JSPDF from a html page

Tags: html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a html page containing many text in tables. I'm using **jspdf** version 1.5 and higher and **html2canvas** libraries for creating a pdf when clicking on a button "generate the pdf".

The pdf is correctly generated.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head> 
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            <title>Template 01</title>      
            <link id="BootstrapCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">      

    </head>

    <body id="toPDF">

            <div id="result">
                <div id="target">
                    <div class="container-fluid">           
                        <p id="generateButton" style="display: none;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="download()">Generate PDF</button></p>
                        <div id="content">
                            <table id="table01" class="table table-bordered table_border">                      
                                ...
                            </table>
                            <table id="table02" class="table table-bordered table_border">                      
                                ...
                            </table>
                            
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </body>

    <script src="jspdf.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function download() {
            let pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4')
            let srcwidth = document.getElementById('toPDF').scrollWidth;

            pdf.html(document.getElementById('toPDF'), {
                html2canvas: {
                    scale: 595.26 / srcwidth, //595.26 is the width of A4
                    scrollY: 0
                },
                filename: 'jspdf',
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                callback: function () {
                    window.open(pdf.output('bloburl'));
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

And the jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/amadese57/17npbu4y

My problem is the tables are sometimes broken at the bottom of the page (and at the top of the next page).
I would like to ***create automatically a break*** when the tables cannot be entirely on the page.

I don't know how to do that and if I can do that in the function pdf.**html()** that I used.

Could you help me please with that ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

you have added the width of the PDF file, try to add the height of the PDF file. And add some more information to the meta data

Comment: can you provide the snippet?